# Как разбить текст и скопировать куски в массив

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, текст

Есть текст в котором встречаются [разныеименафайлов.jpg]
Например:

```
Тли (рус. Тля) или, другими словами, растительные вши — это насекомые, которые размерами не более 6 мм в длину и имеют коричневую и зеленую окраску. Размножение тли происходит настолько быстро, что если бы ими не питались естественные враги, то растений на Земле практически не осталось.
[scale_1200.jpg]
Этих насекомых можно встретить на стеблях, листьях и корнях различных растений. Тли довольно часто наносят значительный вред фруктовым цветам, деревьям, овощам и зерновым культурам. В них природой заложено чрезвычайно сильный рот с хоботком, который торчит из крохотной головки. С помощью него тля протыкает поверхность листа и высасывает из него сок. Впоследствии это растение вянет и, в большинстве случаев, погибает.
Одной из интересных свойств тлей является то, что тело насекомого способно выделять сладкую жидкость, которая получила название «медовая роса», а для муравьев эта жидкость является любимым лакомством. Часто муравьи переносят тлей в муравейник и заботятся о них, словно фермер о коровах. Муравьи обеспечивают их нужным количеством зелени и тщательно оберегают. Когда у муравья возникает желание подоить свою «коровку», он просто поглаживает ее брюшко своими усиками, и на краю брюшка тли выделяются крошечные капли медовой росы. Эти капли и пьет муравей.
[scale_1200 (1).jpg]
У людей нет причин оберегать тлей, поэтому зачастую уничтожают их, опрыскивая химикатами.
```

Мне нужно разделить текст и, заведя двумерный массив массив, поместить в него: 
Первый столбец - Если является изображением jpg [что-то.jpg] - True, если просто текст - False
Второй столбец - кусок текста или имя изображения без '[' и ']'

Для примера выше:

```
    [0] : (False, Тли (рус. Тля) или, другими словами, растительные вши — это насекомые, которые размерами не более 6 мм в длину и имеют коричневую и зеленую окраску. Размножение тли происходит настолько быстро, что если бы ими не питались естественные враги, то растений на Земле практически не осталось.)
    [1] : (True, scale_1200.jpg)
    [2] : (False, Этих насекомых можно встретить на стеблях, листьях и корнях различных растений. Тли довольно часто наносят значительный вред фруктовым цветам, деревьям, овощам и зерновым культурам. В них природой заложено чрезвычайно сильный рот с хоботком, который торчит из крохотной головки. С помощью него тля протыкает поверхность листа и высасывает из него сок. Впоследствии это растение вянет и, в большинстве случаев, погибает.
    Одной из интересных свойств тлей является то, что тело насекомого способно выделять сладкую жидкость, которая получила название «медовая роса», а для муравьев эта жидкость является любимым лакомством. Часто муравьи переносят тлей в муравейник и заботятся о них, словно фермер о коровах. Муравьи обеспечивают их нужным количеством зелени и тщательно оберегают. Когда у муравья возникает желание подоить свою «коровку», он просто поглаживает ее брюшко своими усиками, и на краю брюшка тли выделяются крошечные капли медовой росы. Эти капли и пьет муравей.)

    [3] : (True, scale_1200 (1).jpg)
    [4] : (False, У людей нет причин оберегать тлей, поэтому зачастую уничтожают их, опрыскивая химикатами.)
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Читайте построчно, проверяете, начинается строка с `[` или нет, в зависимости от этого добавляете.

Comment: @вася это для примера выделено, а так эти команды внутри текста, они могут быть и в середине и в конце. Например, строка "Вот Фото [1.jpg], здесь я сплю"

Comment: @вася regex проще.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
result = re.split(r'\[(.+?)\]', yourstr)
print(result)
```

OR

```
import re
result = re.split(r'\[(.*?)\]', yourstr)
print(result)
```

В зависимости от того могут ли скобки быть пустыми.
[Почитайте на досуге.](https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/)

#### Explanation

- `(` & `)` — порядок действий
- `.` — any symbol
- `+` — один или более раз = `{1,}`
- `?` — ленивая регулярка (берет меньше всего)
- `\[` & `\]` — скобки.

#### Example

**in**:

```
import re
yourstr = """
Тли (рус. Тля) или, другими словами, растительные вши — это насекомые, которые размерами не более 6 мм в длину и имеют коричневую и зеленую окраску. Размножение тли происходит настолько быстро, что если бы ими не питались естественные враги, то растений на Земле практически не осталось.
[scale_1200.jpg]
Этих насекомых можно встретить на стеблях, листьях и корнях различных растений. Тли довольно часто наносят значительный вред фруктовым цветам, деревьям, овощам и зерновым культурам. В них природой заложено чрезвычайно сильный рот с хоботком, который торчит из крохотной головки. С помощью него тля протыкает поверхность листа и высасывает из него сок. Впоследствии это растение вянет и, в большинстве случаев, погибает.
Одной из интересных свойств тлей является то, что тело насекомого способно выделять сладкую жидкость, которая получила название «медовая роса», а для муравьев эта жидкость является любимым лакомством. Часто муравьи переносят тлей в муравейник и заботятся о них, словно фермер о коровах. Муравьи обеспечивают их нужным количеством зелени и тщательно оберегают. Когда у муравья возникает желание подоить свою «коровку», он просто поглаживает ее брюшко своими усиками, и на краю брюшка тли выделяются крошечные капли медовой росы. Эти капли и пьет муравей.
[scale_1200 (1).jpg]
У людей нет причин оберегать тлей, поэтому зачастую уничтожают их, опрыскивая химикатами.
"""
result = re.split(r'\[(.+?)\]', yourstr)
print(result)
```

***stdout***:

```
['\nТли (рус. Тля) или, другими словами, растительные вши — это насекомые, которые размерами не более 6 мм в длину и имеют коричневую и зеленую окраску. Размножение тли происходит настолько быстро, что если бы ими не питались естественные враги, то растений на Земле практически не осталось.\n', 'scale_1200.jpg', '\nЭтих насекомых можно встретить на стеблях, листьях и корнях различных растений. Тли довольно часто наносят значительный вред фруктовым цветам, деревьям, овощам и зерновым культурам. В них природой заложено чрезвычайно сильный рот с хоботком, который торчит из крохотной головки. С помощью него тля протыкает поверхность листа и высасывает из него сок. Впоследствии это растение вянет и, в большинстве случаев, погибает.\nОдной из интересных свойств тлей является то, что тело насекомого способно выделять сладкую жидкость, которая получила название «медовая роса», а для муравьев эта жидкость является любимым лакомством. Часто муравьи переносят тлей в муравейник и заботятся о них, словно фермер о коровах. Муравьи обеспечивают их нужным количеством зелени и тщательно оберегают. Когда у муравья возникает желание подоить свою «коровку», он просто поглаживает ее брюшко своими усиками, и на краю брюшка тли выделяются крошечные капли медовой росы. Эти капли и пьет муравей.\n', 'scale_1200 (1).jpg', '\nУ людей нет причин оберегать тлей, поэтому зачастую уничтожают их, опрыскивая химикатами.\n']
```

Comment: Можете объяснить (.*?)\

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG Ну смотрите скобки — для удобства. `.` — any symbol. `+` — один или более раз. `?`—ленивая регулярка (берет меньше всего). `\[` & `\]` — скобки.

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG Вы уже приняли ответ, спасибо писать не надо. Я его удалю.